# Why having a uniqueclustered constraint and index on the same key

Tags: sql-server

I am puzzled about the logic for this which I just found:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PAYER] ADD CONSTRAINT [XAK1PAYER] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([ORG_ID] ASC);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_PAYER_ORG_ID] ON [dbo].[PAYER] ([ORG_ID] ASC);
```

with the following statistics:

```
[XAK1PAYER]:            Reads: 231,630 (230,738 seek 352 scan 540 lookup) Writes: 17
[IDX_PAYER_ORG_ID]:     Reads: 61,395 (26,600 seek 34,795 scan) Writes: 17
```

Wouldn't the unique clustered constraint be implemented via an index anyhow? Why do I see SQL Server chosing to use both, albeit not equally, since an update on one would necessarily also lock the other one?
For space reasons, not because of the extra 17 updates, I would want to delete the second index.

Comment: How many other columns are there? The clustered index includes all columns automatically. In cases where only that column is needed then it makes sense to use a narrower index.

Comment: If you do decide to keep the non-clustered index, may as well make it unique as well. IMO, that can only help any cases that decide to use that index.

Comment: Thanks for looking, I checked and then it became also obvious that SQL Server preferred the clustered index since it's only 7MB versus 2MB for the index. There are 12 additional small columns. So, I think I'm fine deleting the second index.

Comment: Thanks to Ben and Charlieface.